# Multiple HTML5 WebSocket Connection

Tags: php, javascript, html, websocket

Is it possible to connect to multiple html5 websocket connections ? 
As i want to have one websocket connection for read and other websocket connection for write to socket.
I want to open at the same point of time with different connection ids.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    conn = {}, window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;     
    connection1();
});

function connection1() {

// uses global 'conn' object
if (conn.readyState === undefined || conn.readyState > 1) {

conn1 = new WebSocket('ws://ip1:8101');
conn2 = new WebSocket('ws://ip1:8102');

//connection open 
conn1.onopen = function () {
conn1.send("Connection1 Established Confirmation");
};

conn2.onopen = function () {
conn2.send("Connection2 Established Confirmation");
};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need two sockets to write and read.

A websocket can both send data and receive data.

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://ip1:8101'); 
socket.onopen = function(){
    socket.send("Hello server");
};
socket.onmessage = function(message){
    // Handle the message
};
```

Comment: But yes you may have multiple WebSocket connections on a single page if that's really your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you definitely can.

In general, you probably just want to use the same WebSocket connection for both sending and receiving (the full-duplex, bidirectional nature of WebSocket is one of the things that distinguishes it from regular HTTP connections).

There are a few cases where you might want to have a multiple simultaneous WebSocket connections to the same server:

- You are going to send very large messages in one direction or the other. Separating the connections allows you to keep the channel with large messages from affecting the latency of message on the other channel.
- You have different security requirements for each channel. For example, you may allow any browser client to connect to the read only channel, but require authentication on the write channel. Also, running separate processes on the server for the read-only connection and the write connection lowers your vulnerability attack service (separation of concerns).
- You have different scaling requirements for each channel. For example, you may have a consistent datastore behind the server that can have many readers but only a single writer at a time. In that case, it may make sense to serve read-only clients with a thread or process pool WebSocket server to allow those to scale easily.
- The server is actually just a proxy to other WebSocket servers that are not directly visible to the client and they have different functions (e.g. receiving or sending data in your case).

Note that for the cases described above you don't necessarily need to use separate ports and could instead use different request paths in the connection and have logic in the server to get the connections to the right destination process/server.

There are other reasons to have separate simultaneous connections, but unless you have a specific reason I recommend using a single connection since other things being equal it is more efficient (for your browser, intermediaries and the server).